# Singular Values Decomposition Matlab

Tags: matlab, svd

I am researching the above topic and attempting to play about with SVD code in Matlab. I was wondering can anyone explain what the following line of code does?

```
Sh(logical(eye(size(Sh)))) = Sh_diag;
```

I can understand the rest, it's just this line of code that is puzzling me. I have tried running in debugger but still can't understand it! I believe `eye` returns an identity matrix and `logical` converts `Sh` to be 1 and 0's?? But I cant figure out how they work together, especially with `size` of `Sh`? Thank you in advance.

```
%Apply SVD to img1
[Uh Sh Vh] = svd(img1);

% Apply SVD to img2
[Uw Sw Vw] = svd(img2);

% Replace singular values of the img1 with the
% singular values of the img2
Sh_diag = diag(Sh);
Sw_diag = diag(Sw);


if (length(img2) >= 256)
    Sh_diag(1:length(Sh), :) = Sw_diag(1:length(Sh), :);
elseif(length(hidden_img) < 256)
    Sh_diag(1:length(img2), :) = Sw_diag(1:length(img2), :);
end
Sh(logical(eye(size(Sh)))) = Sh_diag;%%%????%%
```

Comment: Have you tried looking functions up in the MATLAB documentation?

Comment: You are right on all counts; `eye(size(Sh))` generates an identity matrix of the same size as Sh. Conversion to logical is required for logical indexing. The whole thing picks the diagonal of the array Sh, which command `diag` also does.

Comment: Just to note: I actually think this is a reasonable question - I reckon it's pretty hard to start from that expression and work out that you need to work out how MATLAB's logical indexing works to see that it's overwriting the main diagonal. Here's the doc on logical indexing http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size(Sh)` returns the dimensions of the matrix `Sh`.

`eye(size(Sh))` creates an identity matrix with the same dimensions as `Sh`.

`logical(eye(size(Sh)))` converts the elements of the identity matrix to logical values.

`Sh(...)` is selecting a submatrix of `Sh` using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). Here it looks like it's just getting the diagonal elements of `Sh`.

`Sh(...) = Sh_diag` is replacing the aforementioned submatrix with `Sh_diag`.

So in all, this is selecting the diagonal elements of `Sh` and replacing them with the values in `Sh_diag`.

Comment: thank you Alex, your answer helped me understand..a very clear explanation!